# how to start a download of a generated zip node

Tags: node.js, express

I want to download a generated zip file. I tried it like this, but it downloads at a 1 byte/s.

```
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/zip'});
res.write(await zip.generateAsync({ type: "base64" }));
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to use nodebuffer type like this:

```
res.write(await zip.generateAsync({ type: "nodebuffer" }));
```

Comment: That code appears to be identical to the code in the question

Comment: sorry i edit the message

Comment: also you can use 
res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/zip");
res.send(content);